# How to scroll UIScrollVIew programmatically

Tags: objective-c

I want to scroll my `UIScrollView` (horizontally). But when the button is pressed it goes the left most side of the scroll view. I want to scroll it 3,4 pixels and when I press again it scrolls another 3,4 pixels

```
- (IBAction)leftScroll:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint pt;
    pt.x = 1;
    pt.y = 0;
    UIScrollView *sv = (UIScrollView *)[self.view viewWithTag:5];
    [sv setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];         
}
```

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try it and set a new position manually.

**Objective-c**

```
  float width = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame);
  float height = CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame);
  float newPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.x+width; 
  CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, width, height);

 [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];
```

**Swift 4**

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let width: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.width
let height: CGFloat = scrollView.frame.size.height
let newPosition: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.x + width
let toVisible: CGRect = CGRect(x: newPosition, y: 0, width: width,   height: height)

scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(toVisible, animated: true)
```

Comment: Great That's Work.
But i want to know which variable's value should i change so that it scroll less than this ??

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];` method. If your scrollView scrolls horizontally then you need to set x value accordingly, else y value.

Comment: This is now the more efficient method.

Comment: To be told when scrolling has ended, this delegate method is your friend: `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Answer (score 3):

You can scroll to some point in a scroll view with the following in Obj-C

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

or Swift

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
```

To do slideshows with UIScrollView, you arrange all images in the scroll view, set up a repeated timer, then -setContentOffset:animated: when the timer fires.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *locatorbutton_frame=(UIButton *)[scrollviewoutlet viewWithTag:numberglobal];
float width = scrollviewoutlet.frame.size.width;
float height = scrollviewoutlet.frame.size.height;
float newPosition = scrollviewoutlet.contentOffset.x-locatorbutton_frame.frame.size.width;//+width;
CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, width, height);

[scrollviewoutlet scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];
```

I found it working fine locatorbutton_frame is the button that i added to the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

**Objective-C**

```
CGRect visible = [targetView.superview() convertRect:targetView.frame toView:scrollView];
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:visible animated:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
let visible: CGRect = targetView.superview().convertRect(targetView.frame, toView: scrollView)
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(visible, animated: true)
```

I tested the Objective-C code, and it works in every screen orientation.